# Laravel - How to Write Validate Combination of unique fields in Foreign key array

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8 web application project, I am trying to validate Dynamic input fields using Request Rules.

I have these two models

```
class AppraisalGoal extends Model
{
  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $table = 'appraisal_goals';

  protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'goal_type_id',
              'parent_id',
              'appraisal_identity_id',
              'employee_id',
              'company_id',
              'weighted_score',
              'goal_title',
          ];

  protected $dates = [];

  protected $casts = [];

  public function goaltype()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalType','goal_type_id');
  }

  public function employee()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','employee_id');
  }

  public function appraisalgoaldetail(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalDetail');
  }

  public function company()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany','company_id');
  }  
}

class AppraisalGoalDetail extends Model
{
 public $timestamps = false;
  protected $table = 'appraisal_goal_details';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'company_id',
              'appraisal_goal_id',
              'kpi_description',
              'activity',
              'start_date',
              'end_date',
              'appraisal_identity_id',
              'employee_id',
          ];

  protected $dates = [
    'start_date',
    'end_date'
    ];

protected $casts = [
 'data' => 'array',
];

public function appraisalgoal()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoal');
  }

  public function company()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany','company_id');
  }
}
```

AppraisalGoal is the main model class while AppraisalGoalDetail is an array of fields that is saved based on the appraisal_goal_id which is a foreign key derived from id in AppraisalGoal.

> Note that it is one-to-many: One AppraisalGoal to Many AppraisalGoalDetail. This is stated in the Controller

```
class StoreAppraisalGoalRequest extends FormRequest
{
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'goal_type_id' => [
            'required', 
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('appraisal_identity_id', $this->appraisal_identity_id)
                ->where('goal_type_id', $this->goal_type_id)
              ->where('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        })               
        ],
        'goal_title' => [
             'required', 
             'string',
             'min:5',
             'max:100',                 
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('appraisal_identity_id', $this->appraisal_identity_id)
                ->where('goal_title', $this->goal_title)
              ->where('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        })                
        ],


        'kpi_description'           => 'required|array',
        'kpi_description.*'         => 'required',

        'activity'           => 'required|array',
        'activity.*'         => 'required',                     

    ];
  } 
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{            
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
      $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
      $employees = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('id', $employeeId)->first();

  DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try {
        $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $request->appraisal_identity_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $request->employee_id;  //$employeeId;   //$request->employees_id
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
        $goal->company_id               = Auth::user()->company_id;

       $goal->save();        

        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){

            $goaldetail = new AppraisalGoalDetail();

             $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description[$key];
             $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];                 
             $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
             $goaldetail->appraisal_identity_id      = $goal->appraisal_identity_id;
             $goaldetail->employee_id                = $goal->employee_id;
             $goaldetail->save();
         }

     DB::commit(); 

            Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
  DB::rollback();
            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    }
}
```

The field in the AppraisalGoalDetail, activity is unique in relation with appraisal_goal_id, employee_id and appraisal_identity_id.

Likewise, kpi_description is unique in relation with appraisal_goal_id, employee_id and appraisal_identity_id

This is what I have so far:

```
        'kpi_description'           => 'required|array',
        'kpi_description.*'         => 'required',

        'activity'           => 'required|array',
        'activity.*'         => 'required',
```

But don't know how to continue since it's an array.

I want to make it similar to what I have here:

```
        'goal_type_id' => [ 
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('appraisal_identity_id', $this->appraisal_identity_id)
                ->where('goal_type_id', $this->goal_type_id)
              ->where('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        })               
        ],
```

How do I achieve this using the Request Rules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't have reputation for comment message, so I ask there. U have an array `kpi_description` and `activity` and they have a keys, and u want to validate they keys?
U can do it with `kpi_description.firstKey.secondKey.thirdKey = ['required']`, or create custom rule, I prefer to do it with artisan command `php artisan make:rule MyRule`. How to use it, u can see in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules